# Minimum scroll amount when programmatically selecting ListItem in android ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout

refering to this question: [how does scrolling in android listview work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949994/how-does-scrolling-in-android-listview-work)

on change from state 2 to 3 the clicked listitem is increased in its size to show more information. if the clicked item was the last one on screen, the extended listitem is not fully visible because the new content flows out at the bottom of the screen.

my current solution is to call "setSelection(index)", if the last visible listitem was clicked. this results in a state were the selection is brought to the top of the screen. this is annoying because the listitem moves from bottom to top.

is there a way to avoid this? this means, is there something to let the listview know, that is should scroll only the minimum amount of pixels, so that the clickeditem is fully visible?
or have i to programm this functionality on my own?

Answer (score 3):

Add a custom OnItemClickListener to the ListView.  Implement OnItemClickListener.onItemClick like this:

```
public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
        int position, long id) {
    View hiddenContent = view.findViewById(R.id.hiddenContent);
    hiddenContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // At this point the layout hasn't be redone and you don't have reliable 
    // measurements on the view.  It would be nice to do something after the view
    // has gone through another layout
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            view.getDrawingRect(r);
            parent.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(view, r, false);
        }
    });
}
```

Whenever you click on a list item to show the hidden content the ListView control will go ahead and do whatever scrolling is needed (or no scrolling if none is needed) to completely show the row.